QGIS : Connexion to OSM failed on computers connected behind a proxy after few minutes
Context: using QGIS on 15 computers connected to my university network behind proxy server.
OSM works well at first, but after a few minutes an orange banner appears on each computer.
Orange banner with the message "the network request to tile.openstreetmap has been interrupted...".
On the other hand, other providers such as Googlemaps or bingMaps work well.
Any idea ?
Do you think that the OSM server breaks the connection because of a large number of requests from the same ip address ?


most likely the lag/latency of your universities proxy server is causing this.
